# Using gulp-svg-sprite with dynamic destination based on source folder

Tags: javascript, svg, gulp, svg-sprite

this is my use case:

I have a source folder with icon 'collections' divided in folders, i.e.

```
src/
    svg/
        basic/
            icon-1.svg
            icon-2.svg
            ...
        ecommerce/
            icon-1.svg
            icon-2.svg
            ...
        social/
            icon-1.svg
            icon-2.svg
            ...
        ...
```

Now, I'd like to export all these icons to SVG spritesheets with [gulp-svg-sprite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-svg-sprite) into this structure:

```
dest/
    svg/
        icons-basic.svg
        icons-ecommerce.svg
        icons-social.svg
        ...
```

Now, I already know how to output a SVG spritesheet with all icons, but I cannot figure out how to pass the **folder** parameter (`icons-{folder}.svg`) to gulp-svg-sprite.

This is my current gulp task:

```js
gulp.task( 'build:svg', () => {
  return gulp.src( path.join( 'src', 'svg', '**/*.svg' ) )
    .pipe( svgmin( { js2svg: { pretty: true } } ) )
    .pipe( svgsprite({
      mode: {
        symbol: {
          dest: '.',
          sprite: 'icons.svg'
        }
      }
    }))
    .pipe( gulp.dest( path.join( 'public', 'assets', 'svg' ) ) );
});
```

Anyone knows some way to do this?